# Replace everything inside a cell except the string I'm looking for

Tags: r, regex

I have a variable in a dataset which is formated in the following way:

```
tornado <- c("TORNADO",                    
             "TORNADO F0",                 
             "Tornado",                   
             "HAIL",        
             "WATERSPOUT TORNADO",       
             "WATERSPOUT-TORNADO",         
             "TORNADOES, TSTM WIND, HAIL", 
             "COLD AIR TORNADO",          
             "HEAT")
```

Tornado is there many times, and my goal is to remove everything inside a cell except the string I'm looking for (obviously Tornado)  so it looks like this:

```
tornado_2 <- ("Tornado",
              "Tornado",
              "Tornado",
              "HAIL",
              "Tornado",
              "Tornado",
              "Tornado",
              "Tornado",
              "HEAT")
```

I have tried it with:

```
gsub(pattern = "", replacement = "", x = vector)
```

and

```
str_replace(string="" , pattern="", replacement="")
```

I used every REGEX combination of `"Tornado"`, `"[Tornado]"`, `"^Tornado."`, `"Tornado[.]."` in the `pattern` part of gsub and str_replace I can think of but to no avail.

I would be grateful for any help someone can provide!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse`: if "tornado" is within string (defined with `grepl`) it returns "Tornado" else it returns original value.

```
ifelse(grepl("tornado", tornado, ignore.case = TRUE), "Tornado", tornado)

# [1] "Tornado" "Tornado" "Tornado" "HAIL"    "Tornado" "Tornado" "Tornado"
# [8] "Tornado" "HEAT"
```

Comment: Another similar one `replace(tornado, grepl("TORNADO", tornado, TRUE), "Tornado")`

Answer (score 2):

Using the fabulous `stringr` library:

```
library(stringr)

tornado <- c("TORNADO", "TORNADO F0", "Tornado", "HAIL", "WATERSPOUT TORNADO", "WATERSPOUT-TORNADO", "TORNADOES, TSTM WIND, HAIL", "COLD AIR TORNADO", "HEAT")
tornado_2 <- str_replace(tornado, regex(".*Tornado.*", ignore_case = TRUE), "Tornado")
tornado_2
```

Which yields

```
# [1] "Tornado" "Tornado" "Tornado" "HAIL"    "Tornado" "Tornado" "Tornado" "Tornado" "HEAT"
```

Principle is like other answers: match `Tornado` case insensitively and replace the complete string if found.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sub()` with `ignore.case=TRUE`.  In the regular expression, just find any occurrence of `"tornado"` and remove the rest of the string with a greedy match `.*` on either side.

```
sub(".*tornado.*", "Tornado", tornado, ignore.case=TRUE)
# [1] "Tornado" "Tornado" "Tornado" "HAIL"    "Tornado" "Tornado" "Tornado"
# [8] "Tornado" "HEAT"
```

You could also write a case-insensitive regular expression by using `(?i)` out front.

```
sub("(?i).*tornado.*", "Tornado", tornado)
# [1] "Tornado" "Tornado" "Tornado" "HAIL"    "Tornado" "Tornado" "Tornado"
# [8] "Tornado" "HEAT"
```